# Convert cv::MatExpr to type

Tags: c++, opencv, operator-overloading

A number of matrix expressions I have evaluate to a 1 by 1 matrix. I would like to do something like:

```
cv::Mat a = cv::Mat(n, m, CV_64F), b = ..., c = ...
double d = a.t() * b * c.inv(); // result happens to be 1 x 1 matrix
```

The way I found to do this is to write:

```
double d = ((cv::Mat)(a.t() * b * c.inv())).at<double>(0);
```

Which is a bit long and very confusing, especially if long expressions are involved.

Is there a better, clearer way to write this? can I somehow overload the operator `double` to apply only to `1x1` `cv::MatExpr`'s?

**Edit**

A simple function to do this is of course possible, though ugly. Any more elegant solutions?

```
double toDouble(cv::MatExpr M) {
  cv::Mat A = M;
  if (A.rows != 1 || A.cols != 1) throw "Matrix is not 1 by 1!";
  return A.at<double>(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is make use of the `cv::Mat::dot` function ([documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=dot#mat-dot)), which takes two `cv::Mat` of same sizes and returns a double.

If the result of your operation is a 1x1 matrix, then you should be able to express it using `cv::Mat::dot`. For example, if a and b are nx1, the two following lines are equivalent:

```
double d = ((cv::Mat)(a.t() * b)).at<double>(0);

double d = a.dot(b);
```

One could also imagine more complex operations:

```
double d = (M.t()*U.inv()*a).dot(V.inv()*b);
```